# jQuery Animation with Zoom In & Zoom Out

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I would like to animate a logo using jQuery automatically when the page loads. First the image needs to zoomed out and then zoomed in and it changes to a different image.How can i do this with jQuery? Please help me. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
   $( "#minion" ).animate({
    height: '50%',
    width: '50%'
   }, 3000,
   function() {
    $( "#minion" ).animate({
     opacity: 0.5
    }, 1000,
    function() {
     $("#logo").html( $(".hiddendiv img, .hiddendiv div").clone() );
    });
   });

  });
```

```css
.hiddendiv {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
  <img id="minion" src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
            <div class="hiddendiv">
                <img src='images/logo-small.png' />
                <div>complete transformation</div>
            </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I have tried like this.    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#logo img").animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'slow');
  });

Comment: I have also tried this. But after adding this code, the image is not showing. $("#logo img").toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: "50%"}, 'slow');
   }, function(){
     $(this).animate({width: "20%"}, 'slow');
      });

Comment: may be this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/d7UjD/9/

Comment: @Krish Thank you. But i have seen this code. It works on mouse hover and mouse leave only. I want the image to be zoomed in and out automatically.

Comment: ya, i think you need to sort it out for your needs with these all http://jsfiddle.net/D7cn8/

Comment: in your title you ask for zoom-in and than zoom-out, than in your question you ask for start from zoomed-out and than zoom-in... If it makes sense to you it does not means it makes sense to anyone else. Does the animation needs to loop infinitely? If yes, how? If not... well ...Please ask a better question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan.. the order of Zoom In and Zoom Out doesn't matter. Yes the animation should loop infinitely. The animation starts with an image zooming in and out or zooming out and in, and then finally another image comes with a text tag line. Is this can be looped so that it works in a continuous manner.

Comment: @ArunaJithin 2 images or more? You should show us what have you tried to loop images. As I see you tried nothing. You just used some `.animate()` - logically it won't loop anything. SO is full of such questions - I just wonder how you missed them all...

Comment: @ArunaJithin it would be nice from you for example if you showed your best effort you did in looping images and than eventually asked how to combine the two - zoom an loop. Please show some code. The best one you have.

Comment: This is what i'm done. I am just a beginner in jQuery. <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>$(document).ready(function() {
           logoAnimate();
   function logoAnimate(){
    $('#logo img').css("cursor","pointer");
    $('#logo img').animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'slow');   
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('#logo img').animate({width: "75%", height: "75%"}, 'slow');
    }, 600, function() {
              logoAnimate();
          });
   }
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like with this fiddle jsfiddle.net/d7UjD/9

```
<img id="zoomimg" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
width="144" height="48" border="0" />
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#zoomimg').css("cursor","pointer");
  $('#zoomimg').animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'slow');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#zoomimg').animate({width: "28%"}, 'slow');
  }, 1000 ); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to some extent.